# текст в DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, pandas, dataframe, текст

Были спарсены данные, но данные получены как не структурированный текст, хотелось бы получить в форме таблицы. Первоначально пытался прочитать через `pd.read_csv`, выдает ошибку `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 13, saw 2`

Затем попробовал вытащить данные через код приведенный ниже:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file = open('output.txt', encoding='utf8')
string = file.read().split('\n')
```

данные получены как текст, хотелось бы получить таблицу как здесь
https://www.kompanion.kg/uploads/annual_reports/a6c4563a462ef9a3e3811e6b44931625392b570e.pdf

файл по ссылке :https://yadi.sk/d/rnSpBT2y3hC1Pg

**Помогите пожалуйста с вопросом**

Comment: Приведенный по ссылке текст не является таблицей - это просто свободный текст с числами. Ваш вопрос это скорее задание для фрилансера нежели вопрос для SO о конкретной технической проблеме. Прстого решения для таких входных данных по-моему не существует

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста хотя бы направление и библиотеки, которые помогут решить поставленную задачу